# sharing video on ios using fb sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, fbsdk

I am very new to programming in iOS and therefore, the question might seem rather stupid but I really do not know what is wrong.

So, I was following sharing in iOS on the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios and I was successful in sharing link, and photo. But I have no idea why I cannot share a video. I am not using `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` but instead, I am using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"xyz" withExtension:@"mp4"]` for the **videoURL**.
Is this the reason why the sharing button doesn't work?

My aim is to let users share content from the app directly. So I do not want them to use `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`.
Here is the code:

```
NSURL* videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"xyz" withExtension:@"mp4"];
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = videoURL;
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
content.video = video;

FBSDKShareButton *button = [[FBSDKShareButton alloc] init];
button.center = self.view.center;
button.shareContent = content;
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

And file xyz.mp4 is in a Media Folder.

Comment: can you paste your code here.

Comment: @RohitKP , I have made the edit to the question to include the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSURL* videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"xyz" withExtension:@"mp4"];
```

replace with this

```
NSURL* videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"xyz" ofType:@"mp4"];

[self saveToPhotoAlbum:videoURL];
```

After that save this video to photo library as Facebook required asset library url.

```
-(void)saveToPhotoAlbum:(NSURL*)url
{
NSLog(@"srcURL: %@", url);

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock videoWriteCompletionBlock =
    ^(NSURL *newURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog( @"Error writing image with metadata to Photo Library: %@", error );
        } else {
            NSLog( @"Wrote image with metadata to Photo Library %@", newURL.absoluteString);
            url_new  = newURL;
        }
    };

    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:url])
    {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url
                                    completionBlock:videoWriteCompletionBlock];
    }
}
```

then

```
FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];    
NSURL *videoURL = url_new;
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = videoURL;
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];   
content.video = video;
shareDialog.shareContent = content;
shareDialog.delegate = self;
[shareDialog show];
```

Comment: thanks for your code, but using alasset we get this warning, --> ALAssetsLibrary' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use PHPhotoLibrary from the Photos framework instead. can you please update this code